# Using transactions for queries which have dependant results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

Here is my script structure:

```
try {
    $dbh_conn->beginTransaction();

    $stmt1 = $dbh_conn->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM activate_account WHERE token = ?");
    $stmt1->execute(array($validate_activate_token));
    $num_rows = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($num_rows) {

        $user_id = $num_rows['user_id'];

        $stmt2 = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET active = 1 WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt2->execute(array($user_id));
        $updated = $stmt2->rowCount();

        if ( $updated > 0 ){

            $stmt3 = $dbh_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM activate_account WHERE token = ?");
            $stmt3->execute(array($validate_activate_token));

            $status = "all fine";

        } else {

            $status = "first problem";
        }

    } else {

        $status = "second problem";
    }

    $dbh_conn->commit();
    echo $status;
    die;

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    $dbh_conn->rollBack();

    $status = "third problem";
    echo $status;
    die;
}
```

The result of my code **always** is `second problem`. Why? And how can I rewrite my code to fix it?

Note that I've tested this condition `if($num_rows) {` separately *(in another script singly)* and it is *true*, but when I write it into script above, it is always *false*.

Comment: `fetch()` will returns FALSE if there are any errors. Are you sure that those queries does not produce such error. It also returns NULL if there are no more records to fetch. Are you sure that queries indeed returns result given the input? You can try to investigate log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of transactions is to make sure that queries that must happen together are never broken up.  In your use case, the first query can be executed in isolation with no downside.

Put the last two in a transaction, but leave the first alone. If the first fails, just don't run the other two.

If the first succeeds but one of the other two (in the transaction) fails so that neither of the two is committed, you're no worse off for having executed the first.

Comment: emm, honestly I cannot imagine what you said .. may you please add the code in your answer?

Comment: There's no code it's logic; I've updated the answer a bit.  If it's still unclear, please tell me what you're worried would happen (ie why are you using a transaction) and I'll rewrite my answer to demonstrate how I address this.

Comment: @MartinAJ I thought you had given up on this answer since you didn't respond. sorry if it was confusing; hope it eventually made sense